# Fragment view pager default primary card till response is received is lagging

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager, adapter

I am setting `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to `ViewPager` in android. `getItem()` method is returning count after response is received. I need to show primary item / fragment which will load till user receives the response. I am returning default count as 1 if list is empty. I am setting view pager adapter in `onViewCreated()` method. But whenever I am launching activity which contains the view pager it is lagging the screen to show default primary data.

Below is my code for state pager adapter :

```
private class TestAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        TestAdapter (FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new AnyFragment();;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
           return listData == null ? 1 : listData.size();
        }

    }
```

How can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think that You can check listData dynamically with a listener or new thread, null returned because getCount method run once when program started, you can send me full program to help you